# For what values ​​of a intersects $y = ax$, $y = \sin x$ just one time?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus

As the title says, for what values of a intersects $y = ax$, $y = \sin x$ just one time?

I am not able to solve this problem, and I really want to know the answer.

Comment: Can you use calculus?

Comment: What are your thoughts on the problem? What have you done so far?

Comment: I suggest you begin by plotting sin(x). Since y=ax is a straight line going through (0,0). Hold a ruler representing y=ax and move it from one side and fix the other at the origin and see for yourself. This is a good practice before you attempt to solve the problem.

Answer (score 1):

Sketch $y = \sin x$ and imagine a vertical line through the origin, which initially has only one intersection point at the origin. Notice that we can rotate it clockwise until it is tangent to $y = \sin x$ at some point $x = k_1$, where $k_1 \in (-\pi/2, \pi/2)$. Likewise, notice that we can rotate it counterclockwise until it is tangent to $y = \sin x$ at some point $x = k_2$, where $k_2 \in (-2\pi, -\pi)$.

To solve for $k_1$ and $k_2$, we need to know when the tangent line of $y = \sin x$ at $x = k$ has a slope that is equal to the slope of the line passing through the points $(k, \sin k)$ and $(0, 0)$. That is, we must solve:
$$
\cos k = \frac{\sin k - 0}{k - 0} \iff \tan k = k
$$
[Solving this equation with Wolfram|Alpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?t=crmtb01&i=tan%20x%20%3D%20x), we see that $k_1 = 0$ and $k_2 = 4.4934\ldots$. Taking their slopes, we have $\cos k_1 = 1$ and $\cos k_2 = -0.2172\ldots$ so that:
$$
a \in (-\infty, -0.2172) \cup (1, \infty)
$$

Answer (score -1):

One intercept is at $x=0$.
Next, $ax=\sin x$, taking derivative of both sides wrt $x$, we get $a=cos x$.
Then, $x=\cos^{-1} a$ is another intercept. So $x=0$ will be the only intercept if $\cos^{-1}a$ does not exist, or $\cos^{-1}a=  0$, which will be the case if $a>=1$ or $a<-1$.

Comment: $a = 0$ isn't an answer; $y = 0$ intersects $y = \sin x$ infinitely many times, at $x = n \pi, n \in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: This answer is correct but you might want to clarify why the derivative is used. We know that it could intersect at one place outside the origin if the place it intersects on the curve is tangent to it. This is what allowed you to derive in order to obtain the necessary parameters for a.

Comment: There is only one point of intersection when $a = 1$.

Comment: Good point, I have corrected the answer, how about now?

Answer (score -1):

I have a partial answer, hope others can build on top of it. For positive values of a, if a>1, you will have only one intersection.

Reason for this is simple, y=x is tangential to y=sinx at x=0. In other words, there will be only one intersection between the two curves when they are tangential to each other. For a<1, the line is no longer tangential, and generates more intersection points. For a>1, the line is no longer tangential, and there are no other points of intersection. Here are the graphs for the same -

[image: only one root for a=1]

[image: only one root for a>1]

[image: more than one root for a<1]

For negative a, I haven't figured out how, but it seems there are single roots up till somewhere around a>-0.2173, for any values below that there seem to be more than one root. This is of course an approximation as I don't know how to arrive the exact value. Hope someone else can help!

[image]